# Linear algebra statment - rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show  that given an $m\times n $ matrix $A$ such that $\operatorname{rank} A = k \leq \min(m,n)$ , then there must exist a $k\times k $ minor of $A$ having $\det \neq 0 $  .

I know that $rankA=k$ implies that there exist $k$  linearly independent rows and $k$ linearly independent columns , but how can I deduce from this the above statement ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take the $k$ linearly independent columns to get a $m \times k$ matrix of rank $k$. Since column rank equals row rank, there are $k$ linearly independent rows. Take those rows to get a $k \times k$ matrix. The rank is $k$ since there are $k$ linearly independent rows. (The latter also implies that the column rank $= k$.) By the invertible matrix theorem any $k \times k$ matrix of rank $k$ has determinant $\neq 0$.

Comment: But why these $k$ linearly independent rows must lie exactly in the $m\times k $ matrix  ? Can't the restriction of the $k$ linearly independent rows to the $m\times k $ matrix be (for example) zero vectors ? Thanks!

Comment: Only consider the $m \times k$ matrix. Its column rank is $k$, therefore its row rank is $k$, thus it has $k$ linearly independent rows. These are the rows you use.

Comment: What gurantees the column rank of the restricted matrix is also $k$ ?

Comment: We know $A$ has $k$ linearly independent columns, because rank$(A) = k$. So we choose these columns to be the columns of the $m \times k$ matrix. Of course they remain linearly independent.

Comment: And don't forget column rank = row rank.

Comment: OK. let me explain the following:
Let us look at $ (1,0, 0 ) $ and $ (1,0,1)$ . These two vectors are obviously linearly independent. But, when we restrict our attention to $(1,0) $ , $(1,0)$ , they are the same vector and in particular no longer linearly independent !

Comment: True, but that is because the first two columns are not linearly independent, so we choose the first en third column to be in your restricted matrix. Then we get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Got it . Thanks !